# ValueError: 'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2 (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas, osmnx

I'm trying to plot the network for a place where I want to check accessibility of my friends for me.

***GDF I'm using:***

```
bbox = [12.8881, 77.5079, 12.9918, 77.6562]

def make_gdf(file_name):
    shp = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(pth, file_name))
    shp = shp[['Name_E','E','N','Area_m2']]
    shp['geometry'] = (list(zip(shp.E,shp.N)))
    shp['geometry'] = shp.geometry.apply(lambda x: Point(x))
    shp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(shp, crs = {'init' :'epsg:4326'})
    return(shp)
friends = make_gdf('BOIS.csv')
```

***Creating the network***

```
def get_bounds(friend_gdf, buffer_fraction):
    bounds = friend_gdf.unary_union.bounds
    x_width = abs(bounds[2] - bounds[0])
    y_height = abs(bounds[3] - bounds[1])
    minx = bounds[0] - (x_width * buffer_fraction)
    miny = bounds[1] + (y_height * buffer_fraction)
    maxx = bounds[2] - (x_width * buffer_fraction)
    maxy = bounds[3] + (y_height * buffer_fraction)
    return(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
def create_network(pois_gdf, bounding_increment):
    coords = get_bounds(pois_gdf, bounding_increment)
    coords = (coords[1],coords[0],coords[3],coords[2])
    return(osm.pdna_network_from_bbox(*coords))
G_BOIS = create_network(friends, 0.2)
```

output:

```
Requesting network data within bounding box from Overpass API in 1 request(s)
Posting to http://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter with timeout=180, "{'data': '[out:json][timeout:180];(way["highway"]["highway"!~"motor|proposed|construction|abandoned|platform|raceway"]["foot"!~"no"]["pedestrians"!~"no"](12.91917720,77.51336840,13.01304320,77.63043640);>;);out;'}"
Downloaded 9,852.9KB from www.overpass-api.de in 4.21 seconds
Downloaded OSM network data within bounding box from Overpass API in 1 request(s) and 4.38 seconds
Returning OSM data with 65,969 nodes and 18,575 ways...
Edge node pairs completed. Took 30.58 seconds
Returning processed graph with 30,323 nodes and 45,812 edges...
Completed OSM data download and Pandana node and edge table creation in 36.52 seconds
```

***Defining a method to plot accessibility***

*define and plot*

```
def plot_Bangalore(network,pois_gdf,distance,n,city_name,highway=['motorway','trunk','primary','secondary'],
                             bounding_increment = 0.2):
    plot_kwargs={'cmap':'gist_heat_r','s':8,'edgecolor':'none'}
    fig_kwargs = {'figsize': [20, 20]}    
    network.precompute(distance) 
    network.set_pois(category='all', maxdist = distance,x_col=pois_gdf['E'], maxitems=1, y_col=pois_gdf['N'])
    access_table = network.nearest_pois(distance=distance, category='all', num_pois=1)
    bmap, fig, ax = network.plot(access_table[n], plot_kwargs=plot_kwargs, fig_kwargs=fig_kwargs)
    ax.set_facecolor('w')
    ax.set_title('{}: Driving distance to nearest boi, meters)'.format(city_name), fontsize=14);
    return(network, access_table)


plot_accessibility_and_roads(G_BOIS, friends, 2500, 1, 'Bangalore')
```

Output:

I got this when running `plot_accessibility_and_roads` method with required details

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-f1d7c3fc45d5> in <module>
----> 1 plot_accessibility_and_roads(G_BOIS, friends, 2500, 1, 'Bangalore')

<ipython-input-12-90e6300937a9> in plot_accessibility_and_roads(network, pois_gdf, distance, n, city_name, highway, bounding_increment)
      5     network.set_pois(category='all', maxdist = distance,x_col=pois_gdf['E'], maxitems=1, y_col=pois_gdf['N'])
      6     access_table = network.nearest_pois(distance=distance, category='all', num_pois=1)
----> 7     bmap, fig, ax = network.plot(access_table[n], plot_kwargs=plot_kwargs, fig_kwargs=fig_kwargs)
      8     ax.set_facecolor('k')
      9     ax.set_title('{}: Driving distance to nearest boi, meters)'.format(city_name), fontsize=14);

~\miniconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\pandana\network.py in plot(self, data, bbox, plot_type, fig_kwargs, bmap_kwargs, plot_kwargs, cbar_kwargs)
    457         bmap = Basemap(
    458             bbox[1], bbox[0], bbox[3], bbox[2], ax=ax, **bmap_kwargs)
--> 459         bmap.drawcoastlines()
    460         bmap.drawmapboundary()
    461 

~\miniconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py in drawcoastlines(self, linewidth, linestyle, color, antialiased, ax, zorder)
   1849         # get current axes instance (if none specified).
   1850         ax = ax or self._check_ax()
-> 1851         coastlines = LineCollection(self.coastsegs,antialiaseds=(antialiased,))
   1852         coastlines.set_color(color)
   1853         coastlines.set_linestyle(linestyle)

~\miniconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py in __init__(self, segments, linewidths, colors, antialiaseds, linestyles, offsets, transOffset, norm, cmap, pickradius, zorder, facecolors, **kwargs)
   1358             **kwargs)
   1359 
-> 1360         self.set_segments(segments)
   1361 
   1362     def set_segments(self, segments):

~\miniconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py in set_segments(self, segments)
   1373             _segments = self._add_offsets(_segments)
   1374 
-> 1375         self._paths = [mpath.Path(_seg) for _seg in _segments]
   1376         self.stale = True
   1377 

~\miniconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1373             _segments = self._add_offsets(_segments)
   1374 
-> 1375         self._paths = [mpath.Path(_seg) for _seg in _segments]
   1376         self.stale = True
   1377 

~\miniconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py in __init__(self, vertices, codes, _interpolation_steps, closed, readonly)
    128         if vertices.ndim != 2 or vertices.shape[1] != 2:
    129             raise ValueError(
--> 130                 "'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2")
    131 
    132         if codes is not None:

ValueError: 'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2
```

**Please help me with the error and please comment If needed more information**

Comment: Please winnow your question down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and replace your screenshots of code and output with the actual text itself.

Comment: Hi @gboeing, I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: Hi @gboeing, It happened to be the case where the osmID for nodes are simplified in Pandana network creation so, the osmID which I get from OSMnx (simplified=False) are happened to be not presented in the Pandana.network... Therefore, the vertices are not able to be plotted.

Comment: Hi @gboeing I still can't plot for the given BBox instead I'm able to plot for every other place. please clarify the problem, Thanks!